# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5568 bytes) in Yii

Tags: php, file-upload

I am working on project using Yii 2.0 framework. I am trying to upload file with size 4MB. it gives me error
**Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5568 bytes)**
When we upload 2MB, it works correct.
I have tried

1. php.ini file added following options

   max_execution_time = 30;
   max_input_time = 60;
   memory_limit = 256M;
   upload_max_filesize = 256M;
   post_max_size = 256M;
2. added ini_set() in root index.php file for all above options

why is it not working? Am I doing something wrong while using the above options?

It shows error at below function in file

vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Gd/Imagine.php

```
$resource = @imagecreatefromstring($data);
```

Comment: Remove the error suppression `@` and see what's what.

Comment: Did you restart apache after changing settings?

Comment: we are using cpanel and yes we restarted.